# When I try to sign in to Mozilla's Backpack I get "Could not verify with browserID!" How can I fix this?

Tags: mozilla, persona, openbadge

I created a backpack account a few days ago. When I try to log in, an external window opens up and 'persona' asks me to sign into backpack as "myemail@example.com." I press "sign in" and I get a message that says "verified!" The external window then closes. The initial login page now has a red bar which says "Could not verify with browserID!" Please see screen shot image.

[image: Error Message]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked. I found it in the Mozilla support forum. Credit goes entirely to the user 'cor-el.'

```
You can reload web page(s) and bypass the cache to refresh possibly outdated or corrupted files.

Hold down the Shift key and left-click the Reload button
Press "Ctrl + F5" or press "Ctrl + Shift + R" (Windows,Linux)
Press "Command + Shift + R" (Mac)
Clear the Cache and remove the Cookies from websites that cause problems via the "3-bar" Firefox menu button (Options/Preferences).

"Clear the Cache":

Firefox/Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Cached Web Content: "Clear Now"
"Remove the Cookies" from websites that cause problems.

Firefox/Tools > Options > Privacy > "Use custom settings for history" > Cookies: "Show Cookies"
Start Firefox in Safe Mode to check if one of the extensions ("3-bar" menu button/Tools > Add-ons > Extensions) or if hardware acceleration is causing the problem.

Switch to the DEFAULT theme: "3-bar" menu button/Tools > Add-ons > Appearance
Do NOT click the "Refresh Firefox" button on the Safe Mode start window
```